# How to start Selenoid and run tests inside it within GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, selenoid

I'm trying to run tests on gitlab-ci and I have to start Selenoid using GitLab CI/CD.
I oriented to this [How to start a selenoid on gitlab-ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890431/how-to-start-a-selenoid-on-gitlab-ci) and received this pipeline

```
test:
  image: gradle:alpine
  services:
    - name: aerokube/selenoid
    - name: selenoid/chrome:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Run all tests"
    - gradle clean test -Dremote.url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub -Psuite=$SUITE --info --stacktrace
```

But I receive error  `java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable`

Also this warnings I can see during setup

```
*** WARNING: Service runner-**********************__selenoid-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
start service container: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-**********************__selenoid-0 AS /runner-**********************-aerokube__selenoid-0-wait-for-service/service (services.go:187:0s)
Service container logs:
2023-06-26T14:46:22.366982773Z 2023/06/26 14:46:22 [-] [INIT] [Loading configuration files...]
2023-06-26T14:46:22.367097645Z 2023/06/26 14:46:22 [-] [INIT] [/usr/bin/selenoid: browsers config: read error: open /etc/selenoid/browsers.json: no such file or directory]
```

Some advice about solving this problem will be usefull. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error message "no route to host" means that network in test container is configured incorrectly. Selenoid error message is self-explaining - "configuration file is missing in Selenoid container".